# Bash: Count N characters within several alphabetically ordered files

Tags: linux, bash

I work with a proof-reader whom I pay certain sum per each N characters (like 500000). He (usually) creates/edits files in alphabetical order. Content/filenames are in (non-latin) utf-8. Simple plain text markdown (.md) or org (.org) files.

I need to find an efficient way to note for myself his "N characters milestones", so that I know when to pay him. For the sake of example, let's say I paid him last time till the character number 3036 in the file "aab.md". He finished that file, went on with "aac.md", "aad.md" and is now on "csdw.md".

1. How can I "measure" N characters (everything included: punctuation, spaces, digits, newlines, braces, etc) within that stream (assuming all of them reside in the same directory)? I.e. I need a bash command that will get "aab.md", 3036, and N as input and provide something like: "csaw.md", 5023 (meaning that N chars ended in that file on that exact letter).
2. How can I list the files, that were accounted for in the previous command?
3. It's less important, but if possible - how will the command from #1 look like, if the files are spread over several directories (also in alphabetical order), like he stopped last time on the character 3036 in the file "a/aab.md" and is now on "np/csdw.md"?

I figured out that `cat * | wc -m` can provide amount of chars in all the files, but it is still far away from what I need.

Comment: Do you want to count any character (including punctuation, spaces, digits, markdown formatting) or just alphabetic ones? Is 5023 the offset in byte, in characters or in alphabetic characters within the file? What about graphemes expressed using more than one character (like those using Unicode combining characters)?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, updated my question: everything included: punctuation, spaces, digits, newlines, braces, etc. Any graphemes. The 5023 offset is in any characters (as above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to suggest using `zsh` instead of `bash`, which is going to make it easier to get a sorted recursive list of the new files since `aab.md`.

```
#! /bin/zsh -
last_file=aab.md offset_in_last_file=3036 n=500000
new_files=(**/*.(md|org)(N))
new_files=($new_files[(Re)$last_file,-1])

(($#new_files)) && perl -Ci -sne '
   $l = length; $go += $l; $o += $l;
   if ($go >= $n) {
     printf qq(file="%s", line=%d, char-offset=%d\n), $ARGV, $., $o + $n - $go;
     exit;
   }
   $o = 0 if eof' -- -go=-$offset_in_last_file -n=$n ./$^new_files
```

For number of grapheme clusters instead of characters, replace `$l = length` with `$l = () = /\X/g`. For instance `é` written as `U+0065U+0301` is one grapheme cluster expressed with two characters (and 3 bytes in UTF-8), while it's one grapheme cluster and one character (and 2 bytes) when written as U+00E9.

With bash 4.4+, and GNU `awk`, you could do something similar for constructing the `$new_files` array with

```
shopt -s nullglob extglob globstar
readarray -td '' new_files < <(
    printf '%s\0' **/*.@(md|org) |
      L=$last_file awk -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\0' '$0 == ENVIRON["L"], 0'
  )
```

With `bash`, you'd also need to replace `./$^new_files` with `"${new_files[@]/#/.\/}"`. (we're adding a `./` prefix to avoid isssues with file names starting with `-` or  `|`, `<`, `>`, whitespace...

Comment: Where do I enter "aab.md" as input? This might be not the first file in the directory. This might be the file after I have paid him several times already...

Comment: @user1876484 `./*.@(md|org)`  is the list of `.md` and `.org` files in the current directory, the first ones of which meant to be the files he has already worked on (those 3036 characters that offset our search).

Comment: I have to be able to specify any file in the directory as a start point for counting (filename + offset), otherwise I need to rearrange files in the directory each time a try to check whether I have to pay him, which I don't want to do (it's a git repository).

Comment: If `3036` is meant to be the offset in the last file he modified last time, and not the total number of characters he has written in the past, then instead of `./*.@(md|org)`, give the list of files starting with that last-modified one.

Comment: How? Is there a regex meaning [aab.."and upwards"].@(md|org) ?

Comment: @user1876484, I think I misunderstood your requirements, see edit.

Comment: As output I get: file="./××.md" ... is there a way to support utf-8 in the output file names? Thank you!

Comment: @user1876484, see edit. I'm not completely clear how the -C arguments work. Looks like only considering input as UTF-8 and leave the rest as _raw bytes_ is the safest. That should allow file names with arbitrary  byte value even if those byte values don't form valid characters.